# Cluster has stale Kerberos client configuration

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cloudera

Use cloudera manager 5.3.0, One of the cluster have this configuation issue,another cluster no problem. 
I can't find a clue to solve this issue, Hours of googling didnt help me. thanks!

```
cluster1
  Cluster has stale Kerberos client configuration.
```

Comment: this porblem  appeared in add new node !!

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/krb5.conf file on your new node is probably different that the one present on your other nodes (or simply not even there). Either 'Deploy Kerberos Client Configuration' from your cluster menu in CM (this will create the krb5.conf file from CM's Kerberos configuration), or copy a working krb5.conf file from another node to the new one.